# ¿Diferencia en Jaspers por el JDK?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, control-de-versiones, jasper

¡Hola buenas!
He estado desarrollando unas plantillas jaspers y probandolas usando como versión del JDK la 1.8.0_202. Mis compañeros tenían una versión algo superior 1.8.0_301 y al probar ven cosas diferentes a mi. El espacio de interlineado ahora es diferente, y algunos otros errores han aparecido. Yo con mi versión puedo verlas como deberían ser.

¿Alguien sabe a que se puede deber este suceso? ¿Alguna solución mediante configuración?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mas que por JDK, sería por la versión de alguna(s) de las [librerías](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-v6-requirements), comenzando por iText. También en ocasiones una fuente que se sustituye por no encontrarse la original puede causar ese tipo de diferencias.

Comment: En principio en el POM tenemos la misma versión de iText declarada, y la fuente si que es la misma lo unico que el interlineado por defecto es superior.

Comment: ¿Cómo comprobaste que es la misma fuente? ¿Cuál es el formato de salida del reporte?

Comment: Definitivamente creo he indentificado el problema, y es el espacio de interlineado que coge por defecto cuando la propiedad LineSpacing = Single. Debe estar en algun propperties o similar